# Phonegap - Blackberry filetransfer with headers 401 error

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, blackberry, file-transfer

This should be a simple solution, but it's driving me crazy.

I am using the FileTransfer plugin to upload a photo taken with the camera to the server, pretty much exactly like the docs.  I am using basic HTTP authentication, which works perfectly on Android and iOS, but on blackberry, it's returning a 401 - Unauthorized error.  Do you have to do something special to get the file upload working on the BB?

I have the whitelist set to *, so that shouldn't be the issue, plus it's working on all the other devices...

```
module.uploadPhoto = function(imageURI, obj) {
    $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
        text:'Sending File...', 
        textVisible:true
    });  

    var uploadURL = CONTEXT+'api/'+obj.id+"/files";

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="files[]";
    options.fileName = 'image_' + imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var params = new Object();
    params.thread = 'object-' + obj.id;
    options.params = params;

    options.headers = {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + loginCreds
    };

    var ft = new FileTransfer();

    ft.upload(imageURI, uploadURL, 
        function(r){
            custAlert('Finished upload!', 'Photo upload successful.');
            $.mobile.loading( 'hide' );  
        }, 
        function(error){
            custAlert('Error uploading image with object: ' +error.http_status+ ' and code - ' +error.code, 'Error Uploading'); 
            $.mobile.loading( 'hide' );  
        }, 
        options, true);

}
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?  I am going a bit crazy... Thanks.

Comment: I find that I have to specify the full url in the whitelist. The wildcard operator never worked for me.

Comment: Hmmm that's an interesting thought.  Let me try that and get back to you.   Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: By "Full URL" do you mean like myurl.com/api/v1/something ?  You whitelist each API call?

Comment: Not every api call - just the main domain and set subdomains to be true. So I'd put <access subdomains="true" uri="http://myurl.com" />